# jQuery .on() at ajax success

Tags: jquery, ajax, events

I would like to bind `.on()` to an ajax "event", meaning that I'd like it to be triggered whenever an ajax response is successfully retrieved.
I don't get how I could bind `.on()` to such an event. Do I need to use `load` like so?

```
$(document).on('load','#elementInsertedByAjax',function(){
    // will do something
});
```

PS I do need to use `.on()` since the whole page is inserted by an ajax call.

Comment: Could the person who voted -1 please elaborate why?

Comment: I was wondering the same honestly, but whatever...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [`.ajaxSuccess()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/)

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {
// will do something
});
```

or bind to

```
$(document).on('ajaxSuccess','#elementInsertedByAjax',function(){
    // will do something
});
```

Comment: is `#elementInsertedByAjax` the form ID?

Comment: @Shaho This can be any ID, see `selector` at [.on() - jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ajax global event [jQuery.ajaxSuccess](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/)

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {
    $( ".log" ).text( "Triggered ajaxSuccess handler." );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$,ajax({
  url:'yoururl',
  type : 'GET', /*or POST*/
  data: {'d1',data1}, /*if any*/
  success:function(returndatafromserver){
         //here you can check the success of ajax
  },error:function(errormsg){

   //error if any

  }

});
```